# How do I find missing point $k$?

Tags: geometry

I found this question in my textbook and hoping I could solve it: basically I have to find the missing points $A(-2,4)$ and $B(1,k)$. I have to find point $k$ if $AB$ is parallel to another line $PQ$ which has a gradient of $-3$.

Of course, I could just guess but I'm wondering if there is another faster way to do it.

Question :

> The interval $PQ$ has gradient $−3$. A second line passes through $A(−2,4)$ and $B(1,k)$ find $k$ if $AB$ is parallel to $PQ$.

Thanks.

Comment: How K is defined?

Comment: @Moti k is just a variable i think, theres supposed to be a number there, we just have to find the missing one, for example (1,k) could be (1,6) where k is 6, solve for k basically

Comment: @Xardous Do you mean $k$ instead of $K$?

Comment: @Andrew this confused my:) I looked for K.

Comment: $K\neq k$.  Perhaps edit your question to match the cases of the letters you're using as variables.

Comment: @Ak19 yes ,    ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parallel** lines have **equal** slopes (gradient).

The formula for the slope(gradient) of a line joining $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

Could you do now?